# My google Page Rank is 1 but a very famous site has a PR of 4, is that rank correct?

Tags: google, pagerank

Recently I just had a look at my Google Page Rank and it's 1 but another site which is much more famous than mine is on 4.

I am confused with the rank: Are these ranks not affected by the websites popularity? I am really confused. Please help me out.

Comment: i am not attaching the link as it will come under promoting my blog.

Comment: Was this page rank calculated from a third party site/plug-in?

Comment: What reason do you have for believing their PageRank is fake?

Comment: @aphex no its been calculated by google page rank official site.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat its not fake but i just want to make sure is it possible that page rank of big and famous blog can be less than that of newer blog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given your comment on Sandy's response, I'm going to say your interpretation of the numbers is backwards, due to the concept of "rank" generally placing 1 at top. The values go from 0 to 10, low to high. Your PR of 1 is *lower* than the other site's 4. Here's a [quick overview at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank#Google_Toolbar), within the much larger article on the PageRank algorithm itself.

Comment: This is just a dumb question IMO and should be closed (if not as unconstructive then a dupe of dozens of similar PR questions).

Comment: Then vote to close it(which I assume you already did). Plenty of other very basic questions get handled here. But there's an answer previous to my own that's gained 7 votes so far, while completely avoiding the actual question; I figured that should at least be addressed, regardless of getting closed or not. Go ahead and downvote me if you want to cancel out whatever small benefit I get.

Comment: @Su' Yes that could be a possibility and if this is the case I guess you answered my question. But can you provide me some link which verifies that its lower to higher???

Comment: @amod0017 See above.

Comment: @Su' my comment wasn't disputing your answer, it was agreeing with it (in fact I upvoted you). Maybe 'dumb' was a bit harsh but immediately jumping to strange conclusions about 'fake' PR shows a fundamental lack of understanding.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat I am not concluding that its "fake" I am confused on that and that anyone could have. Because some very popular blogs are on 4 and my newly started blog is on 1. I dont think any question is "dumb", yes i do agree its lack of understanding bcz IMO every question arises due to lack of understanding. Thats y i asked this here where some one can upgrade me on the same like Su did. I you are confused with the word "fake" then i have edited my own question. Thanks.

Comment: @Su' i agree to you that the above answer tough its not answering the actual question has got 7 vote up and yes there are many basic questions which are handled over here. Anyways thanks for the link a vote up to you and accepting your answer. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 6):

Don't get hung up on PageRank. It is a small part of an algorithm that has over 300 factors in it, changes daily and is updated at least twice majorly each year.

Create quality content and outreach to quality sites in the same niche and your rankings will improve.

Good luck =)

Comment: so it might be possible that your rank can be better than other big blogs available?

Comment: @amod0017 - If your content is better than other said big blogs. The only reason blogs are big after all is because they have good content!

Comment: Hi amod0017 what I mean is that SEO is a lot more complicated than just PageRank. There can bea lot of things that affect it. If you can match your content to a specific unanswered query in the engines, it doesn't matter how big or small you are you will do well =)

Comment: @SandyLee Lee ohk...